# What is 'value' type of the field?

Tags: forms, hooks

Could you please explain how it works:

```
$form['support']['priority']['#type'] = 'value';
```

On my site this code is used to hide Priority field. But I don't understand the logic (I'm pretty new in Drupal). What is really this 'value'.

Comment: It is used in function custom_form_alter

Answer (score 1):

Check [Form API documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#val) on this. It looks like someone hid field `priority` from output so users can't see or change it from form, but value of this field still can be used on form handlers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace #type with a keyword and the value that is to be associated with that keyword.

For instance, to hide a field you could:

```
$form['support']['priority']['#prefix'] = '<div style="display:none;">';
$form['support']['priority']['#suffix'] = '</div>';
```

This basically wraps the field in a div that is set to not display.